# WPF WebView2 - how to enable safe browsing

Tags: c#, wpf, blazor-server-side, webview2

In my webappplication, there is function trigger download ".eml" file then the webview2 (edge) will alert the message "File was blocked because this type of file can harm your device". I know this is the default protected behavior of browser but normally we can ignore it by enabling safe browsing mode.
So how to I can enable it in WebView2? Or how can I handle it in C# code. My web application is implemented by Blazor Server technology

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the CoreWebView2.DownloadStartingevent and the downloads are not blocked anymore.
You can do that in the CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event handler.

Assuming your WebView2 is called 'webView21':

```
private void WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView21.CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting += CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting;
}

private void CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
{
}
```